# Custom RoleBased Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I have an application that authenticates user using a remote system. Users in remote system don't have any role because its multiporpuse nature. I want to assign some roles to each user that authenticated and is valid. Can I use custom membership and rolemanagement? Can I use a dynamic access level to inject authorization to pages?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. I am doing something similar in some apps. Just use the remote system to authenticate, but if authenticated create (or reuse on multiple visits) a local user using membership. Then you can assign roles to that "local user".

So the remote system is only used to authenticate/validate a users credentials, but anything else is managed localy using memberhip and its role management built into ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: there are no local users, all users are defined in remote system, I want to add validated users to some roles.

Comment: If you do not want to or can't alter the remote system you need to create the roles locally...